# How to start Meteor app on specific iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, meteor

After my Xcode upgraded to version 7.3 I'm not able to start my Meteor apps on simulators other then iPhone-6s-Plus. When I enter command

```
meteor run ios
```

having no any simulator running it automatically starts iPhone-6s-Plus. But if I start some other simulator using Xcode then that's what I get trying to run app (using --verbose)

> No target specified for emulator. Deploying to iPhone-6s-Plus, 9.3
>   simulator
>
> ** RUN SUCCEEDED **
>
> An error was encountered processing the command
>   (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=159): Invalid device
>   state

How I can run my apps on any other simulator then iPhone-6s-Plus?

Answer (score 0):

OK, seems it is normal behaviour with Meteor v1.3 described in documentation: http://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#running-your-app

> Currently, this will always run your app on a simulated iPhone 6s
>   Plus. Use ios-device to open Xcode and select another simulator
>   instead.

So command

```
meteor run ios-device
```

will open generated iOS project in Xcode where you will be able to select any other simulator or connected device.